# Out of memory: kill process

Tags: ruby, nginx, server, kernel

Does anyone have any ideas on why these logs are giving these errors - Out of memory: kill process ... nginx invoked oom-killer?

Lately, our cms has been going down and we have to manually restart the server in AWS and we're not sure what is happening to cause this behavior. [log errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDUDX.png)

Here are the exact lines of code that repeated 33 times while the server was down:

```
Out of memory: kill process 15654 (ruby) score 338490 or a child
Killed process 15654 (ruby) vsz:1353960kB, anon-rss:210704kB, file-rss:0kB
nginx invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_adj=0
nginx cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Pid: 8729, comm: nginx Tainted: G        W   2.6.35.14-97.44.amzn1.x86_64 #1
Call Trace:
[<ffffffff8108e638>] ? cpuset_print_task_mems_allowed+0x98/0xa0
[<ffffffff810bb157>] dump_header.clone.1+0x77/0x1a0
[<ffffffff81318d49>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x19/0x20
[<ffffffff811ab3af>] ? ___ratelimit+0x9f/0x120
[<ffffffff810bb2f6>] oom_kill_process.clone.0+0x76/0x140
[<ffffffff810bb4d8>] __out_of_memory+0x118/0x190
[<ffffffff810bb5d2>] out_of_memory+0x82/0x1c0
[<ffffffff810beb89>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x689/0x6a0
[<ffffffff810e7864>] alloc_pages_current+0x94/0xf0
[<ffffffff810b87ef>] __page_cache_alloc+0x7f/0x90
[<ffffffff810c15e0>] __do_page_cache_readahead+0xc0/0x200
[<ffffffff810c173c>] ra_submit+0x1c/0x20
[<ffffffff810b9f63>] filemap_fault+0x3e3/0x430
[<ffffffff810d023f>] __do_fault+0x4f/0x4b0
[<ffffffff810d2774>] handle_mm_fault+0x1b4/0xb40
[<ffffffff81007682>] ? check_events+0x12/0x20
[<ffffffff81006f1d>] ? xen_force_evtchn_callback+0xd/0x10
[<ffffffff81007682>] ? check_events+0x12/0x20
[<ffffffff8131c752>] do_page_fault+0x112/0x310
[<ffffffff813194b5>] page_fault+0x25/0x30
Mem-Info:
Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    2: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    3: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  35
CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  30
CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Node 0 Normal per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 202
CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  30
CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  59
CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 140
active_anon:3438873 inactive_anon:284496 isolated_anon:0
active_file:0 inactive_file:62 isolated_file:64
unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
free:16763 slab_reclaimable:1340 slab_unreclaimable:2956
mapped:29 shmem:12 pagetables:11130 bounce:0
Node 0 DMA free:7892kB min:16kB low:20kB high:24kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15772kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 4024 14836 14836
Node 0 DMA32 free:47464kB min:4224kB low:5280kB high:6336kB active_anon:3848564kB inactive_anon:147080kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:8kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:4120800kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:60kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:28kB slab_unreclaimable:268kB kernel_stack:48kB pagetables:8604kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:82 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 10811 10811
Node 0 Normal free:11184kB min:11352kB low:14188kB high:17028kB active_anon:9906928kB inactive_anon:990904kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:1116kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):256kB present:11071436kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:56kB shmem:48kB slab_reclaimable:5332kB slab_unreclaimable:11556kB kernel_stack:2400kB pagetables:35916kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:32 all_unreclaimable? no
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Node 0 DMA: 3*4kB 1*8kB 2*16kB 1*32kB 0*64kB 3*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 1*2048kB 1*4096kB = 7892kB
Node 0 DMA32: 62*4kB 104*8kB 53*16kB 29*32kB 27*64kB 7*128kB 2*256kB 3*512kB 1*1024kB 3*2048kB 8*4096kB = 47464kB
Node 0 Normal: 963*4kB 0*8kB 5*16kB 4*32kB 7*64kB 5*128kB 6*256kB 1*512kB 2*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 11292kB
318 total pagecache pages
0 pages in swap cache
Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Free swap  = 0kB
Total swap = 0kB
3854801 pages RAM
86406 pages reserved
14574 pages shared
3738264 pages non-shared
```

Comment: For those logs, I wasn't sure how to compress the image to fit more into it but if you need more info on what is there, please let me know and I'll try to post more of it. 
Also, the error shows up multiple times when the server goes down and repeats until it's manually restarted.

Comment: "I wasn't sure how to compress the image to fit more into it" - the proper way is to NOT use *images* but paste relevant parts of logs into the question post as **text**. See also [ask].

Comment: Thank you Tsyvarev, I'll do that next time

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The OOM killer is a Linux kernel process. You're running out of memory. Add memory, add swap, or reduce your memory footprint. Those are your options.

Comment: Thank you Todd. How would I reduce my memory footprint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because your server is running out of memory. To solve this problem you have 2 options.

1. Update your Server's Ram or use SWAP (But upgrading Physical ram is recommended instead of using SWAP)
2. Limit Nginx ram use.

**To limit nginx ram use open the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file and add `client_max_body_size <your_value_here>` under the `http` configuration block. For example:**

```sh
worker_processes 1;
http {
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    ...
}
```

Note: use `M` for MB, `G` for GB and `T` for TB

Comment: Thank you udoyhasan! I'm trying it now. Do you have a recommendation on how much Ram Nginx should use? Or does it just depend on the application?

Comment: That fully depends on your application ram usages

Comment: In a different file (stack/ec2/signage/nginx/prod.tfw.app.conf) there seems to already be a client_max_body_size limit, however it comes after server{} instead of http {}, is that the same thing? Or is that something completely different and I should disregard looking at that and continue with the limit in nginx.conf?

Comment: You have to use in the nginx.conf or sites-enabled/domain.conf or nginx will not get that file configuration

Comment: Sorry, hopefully last question. I'm not sure how much or little I should make the client_max_body_size be, at first I was thinking the application I'm working on should have a lot since it's a large application, so I made it 10B but then I was thinking that would be too much and in that other file I mentioned above, it's currently set to 50M so I was thinking to lower it down to 30M since if I set it to 10B, that technically wouldn't be a reduction, that would be adding more. 

How should I find out exactly or even just roughly how much I should limit Nginx?

Comment: @leonshimizu For your information `10B` is way too much small. `10B` means `0.00001MB` or `0.01KB` and nowadays a simple image file are more than `4KB` and high-resolution images are about `10-15MB`. So if you give your max body size as `10B` it will give an error to your visitor when they surf your site. So as you mentioned that it is a big site you should set it to a minimum of `1G` or `2G`. and you must have a minimum `4-8GB` or more ram.

Comment: Thank you very much @udoyhasan, and sorry about that, when I said 10B I meant 10G. 

Also, thank you, I'm definitely going to test it with 1G or 2G but is there a way to figure out exactly how much I should limit it to so that way it isn't just an educated guess on how much or little I should limit it to?

Comment: @leonshimizu there is no way to test it as it depends on you. For example, if you want to allow your user or application to pass max `10MB` of data per request then you set it to `10M` if you want to allow `2GB` you set `2G`. Fully depends on you and your application. And hopefully, this will solve your issue and if this answer helps you. I hope you will accept my answer and mark it as an answer